# Did these log entries record an intrusion to the server?

Tags: security, log

Here are log entries I found in auth.log. What does **+ ???** mean? And was there an unauthorized access?

```
Feb 11 07:48:32 tts-server su[31265]: Successful su for www-data by root
Feb 11 07:48:32 tts-server su[31265]: + ??? root:www-data
Feb 11 07:48:32 tts-server su[31265]: pam_unix(su:session): session opened for user www-data by (uid=0)
Feb 11 07:48:32 tts-server su[31265]: pam_unix(su:session): session closed for user www-data
Feb 11 07:48:32 tts-server su[31275]: Successful su for www-data by root
Feb 11 07:48:32 tts-server su[31275]: + ??? root:www-data
Feb 11 07:48:32 tts-server su[31275]: pam_unix(su:session): session opened for user www-data by (uid=0)
Feb 11 07:48:32 tts-server su[31275]: pam_unix(su:session): session closed for user www-data
Feb 12 09:46:27 tts-server su[11208]: Successful su for www-data by root
Feb 12 09:46:27 tts-server su[11208]: + ??? root:www-data
Feb 12 09:46:27 tts-server su[11208]: pam_unix(su:session): session opened for user www-data by (uid=0)
Feb 12 09:46:27 tts-server su[11208]: pam_unix(su:session): session closed for user www-data
Feb 12 09:46:27 tts-server su[11222]: Successful su for www-data by root
Feb 12 09:46:27 tts-server su[11222]: + ??? root:www-data
Feb 12 09:46:27 tts-server su[11222]: pam_unix(su:session): session opened for user www-data by (uid=0)
Feb 12 09:46:27 tts-server su[11222]: pam_unix(su:session): session closed for user www-data
Feb 13 12:25:41 tts-server su[22032]: Successful su for www-data by root
Feb 13 12:25:41 tts-server su[22032]: + ??? root:www-data
Feb 13 12:25:41 tts-server su[22032]: pam_unix(su:session): session opened for user www-data by (uid=0)
Feb 13 12:25:41 tts-server su[22032]: pam_unix(su:session): session closed for user www-data
Feb 13 12:25:41 tts-server su[22043]: Successful su for www-data by root
Feb 13 12:25:41 tts-server su[22043]: + ??? root:www-data
Feb 13 12:25:41 tts-server su[22043]: pam_unix(su:session): session opened for user www-data by (uid=0)
Feb 13 12:25:41 tts-server su[22043]: pam_unix(su:session): session closed for user www-data
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Those are probably from a cron job. From `Securing Debian Manual. Chapter 11 - Frequently asked Questions (FAQ)`

> [11.2.3 I found users doing 'su' in my logs: Am I compromised?](http://www.linuxsecurity.com/docs/harden-doc/html/securing-debian-howto/ch11.en.html)
>
> You might find lines in your logs like:
>
> ```
>  Apr  1 09:25:01 server su[30315]: + ??? root-nobody
>  Apr  1 09:25:01 server PAM_unix[30315]: (su) 
>    session opened for user nobody by (uid=0)
> ```
>
> Don't worry too much, check out if this is due to a job running through the cron (usually /etc/cron.daily/find or logrotate):
>
> ```
> $ grep 25 /etc/crontab
> 25 6    * * *   root    test -e /usr/sbin/anacron || run-parts --report
> /etc/cron.daily
> $ grep nobody /etc/cron.daily/*
> find:cd / && updatedb --localuser=nobody 2>/dev/null
> ```

Comment: Thank you sooo much for the explanation and for the link!!

I found these lines:

    ~ > grep www-data /etc/cron.daily/*
    /etc/cron.daily/lighttpd:    su -s /bin/sh -c "find $cache/compress -type f -atime +30 -print0 | xargs -0 -r rm" www-data
    /etc/cron.daily/lighttpd:    su -s /bin/sh -c "find $cache/uploads -type f -atime +1 -print0 | xargs -0 -r rm" www-data